# Reading blocks of data from a large text file in Python

Tags: python, text-files, large-data

[image: File structure and expected output (1,2)]

Dear all,

I am trying to read a very large text file (>100 GB) containing covariances between different variables. The arrangement is such that the first variable is related to all, second is related to all except the first one (e.g., 14766203 or line[0:19] in the figure), and so on (see 1,2, 3 in figure). Here is my sample data:

```
14766203               -10.254364177  105.401485677     0.0049     0.0119       0.0024       0.0014      88.3946    7.340657124e-06   -7.137818870e-06    1.521836659e-06    
                                                                                                                                       3.367715952e-05   -6.261063214e-06    
                                                                                                                                                          3.105358202e-06    
14766204                                                                                                            6.126218197e-06   -7.264675283e-06    1.508365235e-06    
                                                                                                                   -7.406839249e-06    3.152004956e-05   -6.020433814e-06    
                                                                                                                    1.576663440e-06   -6.131501924e-06    2.813007315e-06    
14766205                                                                                                            4.485532069e-06   -6.601931549e-06    1.508397490e-06    
                                                                                                                   -7.243398379e-06    2.870296214e-05   -5.777139540e-06    
                                                                                                                    1.798277242e-06   -6.343898734e-06    2.291452454e-06    
14766204               -10.254727963  105.401101357     0.0065     0.0147       0.0031       0.0019      87.2542    1.293562659e-05   -1.188084039e-05    1.932569051e-06    
                                                                                                                                       5.177847716e-05   -7.850639841e-06    
                                                                                                                                                          4.963314613e-06    
14766205                                                                                                            6.259830057e-06   -8.072416685e-06    1.785233052e-06    
                                                                                                                   -8.854538457e-06    3.629463550e-05   -6.703120240e-06    
                                                                                                                    2.047196889e-06   -7.229432710e-06    2.917899913e-06    
14766205               -10.254905775  105.400622259     0.0051     0.0149       0.0024       0.0016      88.4723    9.566876325e-06   -1.357014809e-05    2.378290143e-06    
                                                                                                                                       5.210766141e-05   -8.356178456e-06    
                                                                                                                                                          4.016328161e-06
```

Now I wanted to be able to extract them as blocks in python or at the least read one block and exit the file read (e.g., 1, 2, 3). I couldn't succeed but here is my effort:

```
with open(inFile, 'rb') as f: listData = []
   for line in f: 
   MarkNumber = None; 
   if line[0:19].strip() != '' and line[23:36].strip() !='':
      MarkNumber = str(line[0:19].strip())                                                        
   if line[0:19].strip() == MarkNumber and len(line[23:36].strip()) !=0:
       isMark = True                                                
   if line[0:19].strip() != MarkNumber and len(line[23:36].strip()) !=0:
       isMark = False                                               
   if isMark == True:                                               
        ListOfData.append(line)
```

The ListOfData tends to read all lines until the end of file. So it does not really help.

Any help to get this thing sorted out will be appreciated.

Thanks Nakhap

Comment: Do you want to parse a row into columns, or do you want to return the data as text rows? If the former, you could convert the text file to a CSV, then use the Python pandas library for that purpose.  It looks like your columns are delimited anyway, which should make CSV conversion simpler.

Comment: Hi Suzanne, Thanks for the response. I would like them in text rows with each block as a list item, so that I can process it by block. You can see in the figure how a block should be. It might be ok to use csv but the file also contains a lot of texts in between which I did not show there.

Comment: So if there's something in the second column, that should signal "start a new block," right?

Comment: that is right Suzanne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use regex to find blocks that have a second chunk of numbers within, say, 15 characters of the chunk of numbers that begins a line?

```
import re

inFile = 'C:/path/myData.txt'
myregex = r'(^[.0-9e-]{1,15}[\W]{1,15}[.0-9e-])'
thisBlock = []

with open(inFile, 'rb') as f:
  for line in f:
  if re.search(re.compile(myregex),line):
       print("Previous block finished.  Here it is in a chunk:")
       print(thisBlock)

       print("\n\n\nNew block starting")
       thisBlock = [line]
  else:
       thisBlock.append(line)
```

The regex expression `myregex` looks for 1 to 15 `{1,15}` characters of whitespace `[\W]` in between two numeric sequences `[.0-9e-]` -- this looks for digits 0-9, as well as decimal points, negative signs, and the exponent e.  The first {1,15} in the expression assumes that your first numeric expression at the start of the row is at least 1, but less than 15, characters.

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution. I however, cannot append the last block that is generated after the 'print(thisBlock)'. Any trick for that Suzanne?

Comment: Suzanne, can you explain me on the use of 15 characters? My file read is only able to extract about 16000 lines using your code. Again please be reminded about the earlier question....

Comment: @Khandu, I think you need to use the @ sign in front of the user name to alert Suzanne via inbox.

Comment: @Khandu I'm a little confused about what you mean by `appending the last block`.  Also, do you want to return just the first few blocks, as stated in your original question, or read through the whole file, as in your previous comment?

Comment: @Suzanne Thanks. 1. The last block does not seem to contain the first line. But that is ok. 2. Yes I want to read through the whole file and get all the blocks. Thank you for responding again.